# Replace a block in xml with linux script or a procedure

Tags: xml, bash

I need to pull an xml message from the database and make some edits and update in the database. I was trying to write a procedure for it but then there was one condition I could not implement.

Here is a sample message that I need to convert -

```
<Test>
  <First>1</First>
  <Second>2</Second>
</Test>
```

I want to change it to be like-

```
<Test>
  <First>1</First>
</Test>
<Test>
  <Second>2</Second>
</Test>
```

There can be up to 4 elements inside `<test>` tag. So,

```
  <Test>
    <First>1</First>
    <Second>2</Second>
    <Third>3</Third>
  </Test>
```

Would need to be converted into -

```
<Test>
  <First>1</First>
</Test>
<Test>
  <Second>2</Second>
</Test>
<Test>
  <Third>2</Third>
</Test>
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I assume you want this operation to be idempotent -- so, do we only have any effect if the outer `Test` has at least two direct children, neither of which is `Test`? Can you describe the desired logic as an algorithm, rather than only by example?

Comment: BTW, do you have `xsltproc` installed? If so, your best bet at a safe and robust answer using tools you already have installed would probably be to use it.

Comment: By the way -- a valid XML document can have only one root. Is there any wrapper not shown in the question *around* the content you're changing, or are what you're providing complete documents (in which case your desired output isn't valid XML)?

Comment: Your output format is no longer well-formed XML. Also, I recommend you use an XML technology for this, e.g. xmlstarlet, XQuery or XSLT. Tag your question with one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F"\n" -v RS="</?Test>" '{b=b?b:RT;
                                for(i=2;i<NF;i++){
                                     print b; 
                                     print $i; 
                                     print RT
                                }}' file

<Test>
    <First>1</First>
</Test>
<Test>
    <Second>2</Second>
</Test>
<Test>
    <Third>3</Third>
</Test>
```